# What are the valid combination of ObjectName and ComponentName in mqsireportproperties command?

Tags: command-line-arguments, ibm-integration-bus

I am trying to list out all properties for all objects in IBM Integration Bus.
The mqsireportproperties command takes a combination of 2 parameters

```
-b ComponentName, the valid values are httplistener, securitycache, cachemanager, pubsub or webadmin

-o ObjectName this can be any value from the list entities returned by AllReportableEntityNames
```

Where is the documentation that gives us the correct combination of options between these to parameter?
For example this is a valid command

```
mqsireportproperties TESTNODE_root -o 'HTTPConnector' -b webadmin -a
```

where as this is **not**

```
mqsireportproperties TESTNODE_root -o 'HTTPConnector' -b cachemanager -a
```

**What are the valid combination of ObjectName and ComponentName in mqsireportproperties command?**

Answer (score 0):

There is not a centralized view for what you asking for. The IBM Integration Bus documentation sometimes list this by certain types of administration tasks.

The [mqsireportproperties documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an09150_.htm) by the end has several of examples but do not cover all.